# How to extract a comma separated number from a string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, extract

I'm VERY new to regex and can't get my head wrapped around it completely yet.

I'm trying to write two regex's - you'll need to tell me if they're even possible.  Both are based on VB.net syntax.

Regex 1:
The string I'm testing against -
    Size on disk: 25,754,900,936 bytes

It has a handful of leading spaces, but the text is ALWAYS the same.  I'm trying to extract out just the number (25,754,900,936).

I've tried a handful of regex's, but I can't get everything on one line.  The commas are messing me up and returning multiple matches (For example, \d+\W+ gives me four matches, one for each set of numbers separated by commas.)

The best I've done is [0-9/,]* but that gives me 25 empty matches and one match (On match 19) of the number.  I need this to match on match 1.

Doable?  Seeing a regex where I can extract a number like this out of a string would be really helpful.

Regex 2:
Same idea, but now multiline.

The string I'm testing against -

```
           0 File(s)              0 bytes
           1 File(s)         11,546 bytes
           1 File(s)        259,584 bytes
           3 File(s)          5,682 bytes
       17218 File(s) 25,705,262,230 bytes
```

I need JUST the total bytes on that last line (25,705,262,230).  Is it possible to do this in a multiline search?  Same deal - text is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first regex to extract just the number, try this:

```
(\d+,?)+
```

It will match groups of one or more digits (0-9), optionally followed by a comma (`,?`) which occur one or more times.

For your multiline string, if you know that the string will always end in 'bytes', try this:

```
(\d+,?)+(?=\s*bytes$)
```

This will again match similar to the first regex, although the line must end in 'bytes' as `$` signifies the end of the line.  You then need to extract the captured value:

```
'Regex is your regular expression object containing the second regex
regex.Match([your string]).Value
```

Comment: James - both did indeed work, but I'm not actually using this in .net - I'm using a third-party app that can do regex's.  Unfortunately, it can only work with the first capture, first group.  Any way on the second regex to get it into that position?  Right now it still has the word bytes on the first group first capture, but otherwise it's perfect.

Comment: @Pat Ah I see no worries. You need to add a positive lookahead so that the end of the string (the 'bytes' you do not wish to capture) will not be included. I have amended the second regex above. Let me know if that works - I extracted the matched value (without the 'bytes') simply by using `regex.Match([your string]).Value`

Answer (score 1):

For extracting the number, use a regex like:

```
/Size on disk: ((?:\d+,?)+)/
```

and then extract the first captured group. In JavaScript:

```
var s = "Size on disk: 25,754,900,936 bytes";
var bytes = s.match(/Size on disk: ((?:\d+,?)+)/)[1];
// "25,754,900,936"
```

That regular expression says (from inside out)

- `\d` — Find a digit character

  - `+` — …well, OK, find one or more of them
- `,` — followed by a literal comma

  - `?` — …well, maybe; it's OK if you can't find one of those
- `(?:…)` — now, take all of that and treat it as a group that we don't need to save

  - `+` — allow that group to happen any number of times
- `(…)` — capture the result of ALL of that and save it for me
- Oh yeah, and ensure that right before all of this you can find the text `"Size on disk: "`

---

On the multi-line, anchor your regular expression to the end of your input. Again, here's an example in JavaScript:

```
var re = /((?:\d+,?)+) bytes$/m;
var total = multiline.match(re)[1];
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/uFfsc/1/

It's up to you to learn how to anchor your regexp in .NET to the end of the input.

Comment: Phrogz - thanks for the explanation.  James's regex above worked well, and unfortunately (My fault for not mentioning it), I'm using a third party app which just accepts regex's.  It's not a programming language that I can add JavaScript, etc.  But your explanation was great and helped me understand a little better what the regex's are doing.

Comment: Good addition with the non-capturing parentheses so a back reference is not created :)